# step 4 "Run the Samples" of Facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, api, photos

i use eclipse on mac (version 10.7.5) to create a Facebook application (api 8)  on android

when i try to follow the instructions of Facebook api to develop android application.

i did all the things the site told me to, and the packages and classes seems ok,
but when i try to run any of the Facebook applications like ProfilePictureSample for instance
its shouts that i problem

i tried to build an application called CTPuppy

the console writes:

```
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] res/drawable-hdpi/furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] res/drawable-hdpi/furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] res/drawable-hdpi/furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] res/drawable-hdpi/furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] res/drawable-hdpi/furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/workspace1/CTPuppy/res/values-v11/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-12-08 08:47:43 - CTPuppy] /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/workspace1/CTPuppy/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg exists in your res/drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: it exist, and i also did clean for the project.

Comment: It might be the problem of "-". Change your file name to replace all '-' with '_'. Or just remove all '-' as TanjaV said.

Answer (score 0):

The file name

```
furr-blitzen-trapper-cd-cover-art.jpg
```

is an invalid file name because of the '-'. Change your file name to replace all '-' with '_'. Or just remove all '-'.

Comment: i changed the file name to without "_" or "-"
and now the console tells me that:
[2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time. [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] Versions found are: [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b/facebook/libs/android-support-v4.jar [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] Length: 349252 [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389

Comment: [2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] Path: /Users/itaiirdam/Documents/workspace1/CTPuppy/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy]  Length: 385677
[2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy]  SHA-1: b9c504522d97f64025c387493d3989e52bc617bd
[2012-12-08 10:03:14 - CTPuppy] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: This is a different problem. You should probably clean your project, and check your libraries

Comment: yep, thanks.   i clean my project but i need to learn more about that libraries

Comment: If the answer answers your first question you should accept the answer. If there is another problem, then ask a new question